# Make my mobile website share on iphone using native share sheet?

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, mobile-safari, facebook-social-plugins

I have a custom share button on my website. When I click in on my desktop computer I have it opening up a AddThis share popup. That works fine. When I open my website on my iPhone, my custom share button does nothing. How do I make it open my iPhone's sharing options Facebook, Twitter, Message, Mail? I don't care if I use a 3rd party share tool or not, I would prefer something like if(iphone)window.opennativesharesheetftw()

In chrome on my iPhone the browser's share options look different but when you click facebook it uses the good native facebook share sheet. I want to use that. I don't want to open a new browser window to the mobile facebook website.

I've tried googling this but I get no results that have anything to do with what I'm searching for.

Then when the user clicks Facebook I want this to show up:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope Safari provides no interface to programatically display its UIActivityViewController - Could you imagine how bad that would be if sites could put javascript code that brought that up whenever they felt like it? YIKES!

You could bring it up whenever you'd like if you were creating your own application, but as far as what you are able to do just creating a mobile site, there aren't too many options.

One 'trick' I've seen some sites do is detect that you're on iOS and put a fixed image at the bottom of the page that points to the share button. Well, I've seen people do that for the bookmark button, but you get the idea.